# Rails: Loop over every hour between two times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, time

If I define the following:

```
    timetogoback = Time.zone.local(2012,8,01,0,0)

    timeupto = Time.zone.local(2012,9,12,12,0)
```

As two times, how do I then create a loop that iterates over every hour between those times?

I am trying to run a once off task to create by-hour summary tables from existing data. So I want to loop and set the created_at to the correct hour so that the data calculated and saved is correct for that exact hour.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `while` loop that increments `timetogoback` until it is greater than `timeupto`

```
while timeupto > timetogoback do
  timetogoback += 1.hour
  print "#{timetogoback}\n"
end
```

Comment: There's RoR tag in the question, so you can make it even more clear by using `1.hour` instead of `60*60` :)